# Definition of a stochastic process with orthogonal increments

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ be a probability space and $X_t:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a stochastic process indexed by, e.g. $t \in [0,\infty)$.
Then $X = (X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is said to have orthogonal increments if $X_t \in L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ and if
$$
\mathbb{E}(X_t - X_s)(X_{t'} - X_{s'}) = 0 \quad \text{ for all } \quad [s,t],[s',t'] \subseteq [0,\infty) \text{ such that } [s,t] \cap [s',t'] = \emptyset\,.
$$
In the language of Hilbert spaces this just means that $\langle X_t - X_s, X_{t'} - X_{s'}\rangle_{L^2} = 0$ if $[s,t] \cap [s',t'] = \emptyset$.

Now, if $X_t$ is a vector-valued process, i.e. $X_t:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^m$, then a natural extension of this definition would be just to define an orthogonal increments process as a process such that
$X_t \in L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P;\mathbb{R}^m)$ and
$$
\langle X_t - X_s, X_{t'} - X_{s'}\rangle_{L^2} = \mathbb{E}(X_t - X_s)^\top (X_{t'} - X_{s'}) = 0 \quad \text{ for all } \quad [s,t],[s',t'] \subseteq [0,\infty) \text{ such that } [s,t] \cap [s',t'] = \emptyset\,.
$$
This is, however, **not** how some textbooks define it. E.g. in P. Caines "Linear stochastic systems" orthogonal increments are defined by (notice the position of the transposed sign!)
$$
\mathbb{E}(X_t - X_s) (X_{t'} - X_{s'})^\top = 0 \quad \text{ for all } \quad [s,t],[s',t'] \subseteq [0,\infty) \text{ such that } [s,t] \cap [s',t'] = \emptyset\,.
$$
which appears to be a stronger requirement, as $\mathbb{E}(X_t - X_s)^\top (X_{t'} - X_{s'}) = \operatorname{tr}(\mathbb{E}(X_t - X_s) (X_{t'} - X_{s'})^\top)$.

Thus my question:

> How are these definitions related and how can one formulate the second definition as a condition on $X_t$ in the Hilbert space $H = L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P;\mathbb{R}^m)$ ?

I would also appreciate any reference, where vector-valued stochastic processes are treated from a functional analytic (e.g. Hilbert space) point of view.

Comment: The transpose sign in the orthodox textbook definition
$$
\mathbb{E}(X_t - X_s) (X_{t'} - X_{s'})^\top = 0
$$
ensures that every pair of components of $X$ have orthgonal increments, i.e.,
$$
X^i_t-X_s^i\quad \text{ and }\quad X^j_t-X^j_s
$$ are orthogonal in $L^2(\Omega,{\cal A},P)\,.$ This is in line with the situation in an $n$-dimensional Brownian motion where orthogonality is replaced by independence.

Comment: A book that could help you further is [G. Da Prato, J. Zabczyk *Stochastic Equations in Infinite Dimensions*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/stochastic-equations-in-infinite-dimensions/17CB9F06965F01647D576C62D28049F6).

Comment: Hi Andrei: This may not cover the multi-dimensional case ( and its not as advanced as what Kurt recommended )  but it's the best I've seen in terms of more elementary concepts.  https://purl.stanford.edu/qc479yc7778